# Jhipster application error "the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)"

Tags: jhipster

I generate an application with jhipster generator and when I tried to run this application the execution was successful and without error but the display of the application was strange and when I inspect the home page of the application I got this error : "the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" 
I really can't understand the reasen of this error or how can I solve it

Comment: This is normal until you get logged in

Comment: But my problem is that the display of the application is not normal, it seems there is a problem with html or javascript file , I don't understand it

Comment: Yes but it's probably not related, look at the browser console

Comment: thank you @GaëlMarziou I solved the problem, some css file was missed so I typed "grunt serve" in the project terminal and it was solved